# mysql to mysqli delete

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, sql-delete

I am converting MySQL to mysqli and am totally stuck on the delete

```
function RemoveItem($itemid) {
    global $db_user, $db_password, $db_database;
    $link_id = mysqli_connect("$db_host", "$db_user", "$db_password", "$db_database");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    mysqli_query("delete from cart where cookieid = '" . GetCartId() . "'    and itemid = $itemid");
}
```

Comment: have you got any error

Comment: `mysqli_query($link_id, "delete from c.......")`..

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_query.asp

Comment: Yeeeeeesssss....?! "Stuck" where/how/why/what/whom/when?

Answer (score 0):

go through the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

```
mysqli_query($connection,"your query");
```

or

```
$connection->query("your Query");
```